# Compare sublist of a list for objects that change, in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a List of objects that has a sublist of strings and these structures can change between days and I'm looking to compare them to see if a change was made.

```
public class Recipe
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

The `ID` field is the same between versions of the list and `Ingredients` is just a list of *strings*.

```
List<Recipe> list1 = GetRecipes("2013-06-20");
List<Recipe> list2 = GetRecipes("2013-06-21");
```

I'm trying to find all `Recipe`s that have ingredient changes between days. I've been able to come up with a Linq statement to find new `Recipe`s that are in *list2* but not *list1* by something like this

```
var newRecipes = list1.Where(x => !list2.Any(x1 => x1.ID == x.ID))
    .Union(list2.Where(x => !list1.Any(x1 => x1.ID == x.ID)));
```

But, I haven't figured out yet how to select only `Recipe`s that have had `Ingredient` changes between lists.

```
var modifiedRecipes = list1.Where(x => !list2.Any(x1 => x1.ID == x.ID && x1.Ingedients.SequenceEqual(x.Ingedients)))
    .Union(list2.Where(x => !list1.Any(x1 => x1.ID == x.ID && x1.Ingedients.SequenceEqual(x.Ingedients))));
```

How can I get a list of objects that have had changes in  a sublist of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will get you pairs of every non matching recepies of the same ID. You have to sort the ingredients lists for SequenceEqual to work though.

```
var changed = from older in GetRecipes("2013-06-20")
              join newer in GetRecipes("2013-06-21") on older.ID equals newer.ID
              where !older.Ingredients.SequenceEquals(newer.Ingredients)
              select new { older, newer };
```

Comment: This is very inefficient when better options are available.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Actually, it's much more efficient then yours, as you do not check first for ID equality to eliminate recipies with different ID. Your solution would run much more `SequenceEquals` (how many more depends on implementation of `ExceptBy` which is unnecessary 3rd party code)

Comment: ExceptBy is Jon Skeet's code. /programmingmeme And actually, mine is ~O(m+n) as ExceptBy uses a hashset internally, and so therefore only checks if there's a hashbucket collision. Yours is something like O(mn) and a bit more.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance even after my proposed fix, your solution is less performant than mine, as evidenced by [this code](http://pastebin.com/hmD16m3j). Comlexity of my solution is nowhere near your claimed O(nm). Notice I first perform join on the ids, which is done using hashet and has complexity O(n+m). Then for every pair of elements with equal ID I check for sequence equality.

Comment: Really? Also, if you tried to optimize my code (you didn't), not only would you realize that hashsets depend on some uniformity with prime number divisibility, some of which are 17 and 13. Also, Aggregate is slow compared to a foreach loop. Also, don't instantiate a new `EnumerableComparer` in each run of the loop. With that, my solution is faster. See my code here: http://pastebin.com/SenZA8S7

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance not gonna argue optimization specifics now that the solutions are the same complexity, though on my machine results are: First method: 3036 / Second method: 2368.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do that.Get [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) first of all (it can be done without it, however it's slightly more inefficient, ask me if you want it). However, before that we need to add a better enumerable `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class EnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public void Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        int x = 31;
        foreach (T element in obj)
        {
            x += 37 * element.GetHashCode();
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

After that it's as simple as this:

```
var modifiedRecipes = list2.ExceptBy(list1, n => n.Ingredients,
    new EnumerableComparer<string>());
```

If you're going to be using this around your code, I wouldn't instantiate a new EnumerableComparer all the time, as they're all the same. Use the same instance for each type.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This seems to return all `Recipe`s in _list1_ rather than the ones that changed. Is there any sort of additional comparison i should be doing?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `GetHashCode` will always be different on different `Ingredients` objects, as it only checks for referential equality (thus `Equals` is never called). You could fix that by using for example `return obj.Aggregate( 13, (acc, item) => acc * 17 + item.GetHashCode());`